# Input file with custom button style in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create input file with my custom button style, the problem is that the browse button doesn't work, i.e it doesn't open the file dialog:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="No file selected" id="txtPath"  />
<input type="button" value="Browse..." id="btnBrowse"  />
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button doesn't do anything. If you want that button to be used to upload something, use Javascript to "click" de invisible file input. Add an OnClick to your button:

```
<input type="button" value="Browse..." id="btnBrowse" onClick="browse()" />
```

And add this to the Javascript:

```
function browse() {
    console.log("hi")
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}
```